# Why is the stopwatch not timing my method correctly?

Tags: c#

I am trying to test the performance difference of my quicksort and mergesort methods, but for some reason the first cycle of the loop always show exactly 0.003 milliseconds and the rest 0 milliseconds.

```
public static void RunDiagnostics(int[] rangeOfLengthsToTest, int numOfTestsPerLength)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    int[] array;
    double totalQuicksortTime, totalMergesortTime;
    for (int i = rangeOfLengthsToTest[0]; i <= rangeOfLengthsToTest[1]; i++)
    {
        totalQuicksortTime = 0;
        totalMergesortTime = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < numOfTestsPerLength; k++)
        {
            array = GetArray(i, new int[] { -9999, 9999 });
            stopwatch.Start();
            QuickSort((int[])array.Clone());
            stopwatch.Stop();
            totalQuicksortTime += stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            stopwatch.Restart();
            MergeSort((int[])array.Clone());
            stopwatch.Stop();
            totalMergesortTime += stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Quicksort took an average of {totalQuicksortTime / numOfTestsPerLength} milliseconds to sort arrays with a length of {i}.");
        Console.WriteLine($"Mergesort took an average of {totalMergesortTime / numOfTestsPerLength} milliseconds to sort arrays with a length of {i}.");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Even when I print the elapsed milliseconds of each run instead of averaging them out, it still only times zeros.

edit: Here are my methods (sorry if they are a bit junk):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            RunDiagnostics(new int[] { 3, 12 }, 1000);
    }
    
public static int[] GetArray(int length, int[] RangeOfNumbers)
    {
        Random rng = new Random();
        int[] arr = new int[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            arr[i] = rng.Next(RangeOfNumbers[0], RangeOfNumbers[1]);
        return arr;
    }
    
    public static void QuickSort(int[] array)
            {
                QuickSort(0, array.Length - 1);
                void QuickSort(int left, int right)
                {
                    if (right > left)
                    {
                        if (right - left == 1)
                        {
                            if (array[left] > array[right])
                                Swap(left, right);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Swap(GetStartingPivotIndex(), right);
                            int pivot = Partition(left, right - 1);
                            QuickSort(left, pivot - 1);
                            QuickSort(pivot + 1, right);
                        }
                    }
    
                    int GetStartingPivotIndex()
                    {
                        if (array[left] > array[right])
                        {
                            if (array[left + (right - left) / 2] > array[right])
                                return right;
                            else
                                return left + (right - left) / 2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (array[left + (right - left) / 2] > array[left])
                                return left;
                            else
                                return left + (right - left) / 2;
                        }
                    }
    
                    int Partition(int low, int high)
                    {
                        while (low != high)
                        {
                            if (array[low] < array[right])
                                low++;
                            else if (array[high] > array[right])
                                high--;
                            else
                                Swap(low, high);
                        }
                        Swap(low, right);
                        return low;
                    }
    
                    void Swap(int index1, int Index2)
                    {
                        int temp = array[index1];
                        array[index1] = array[Index2];
                        array[Index2] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
    
    public static void MergeSort(int[] array)
            {
                MergeSort(array);
                int[] MergeSort(int[] array)
                {
                    int[] array1 = array.Take(array.Length / 2).ToArray();
                    int[] array2 = array.Skip(array.Length / 2).ToArray();
    
                    if (array1.Length > 1)
                        MergeSort(array1);
                    if (array2.Length > 1)
                        MergeSort(array2);
    
                    int c1 = 0;
                    int c2 = 0;
                    bool flag1 = false;
                    bool flag2 = false;
    
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (flag1 && !flag2)
                        {
                            array[i] = array2[c2];
                            if (c2 == array2.Length - 1)
                                flag2 = true;
                            else c2++;
                        }
                        else if (flag2 && !flag1)
                        {
                            array[i] = array1[c1];
                            if (c1 == array1.Length - 1)
                                flag1 = true;
                            else c1++;
                        }
                        else if (!flag1 && !flag2)
                        {
                            if (array1[c1] < array2[c2])
                            {
                                array[i] = array1[c1];
                                if (c1 == array1.Length - 1)
                                    flag1 = true;
                                else c1++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                array[i] = array2[c2];
                                if (c2 == array2.Length - 1)
                                    flag2 = true;
                                else c2++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return array;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Apart from what @Austin said, if you want to measure performance properly, consider trying out [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet)

Comment: @Austin I added my methods (sorry if it's a mess. Still new to this stuff).

Comment: If `rangeOfLengthsToTest` only ever contains two values, why not just take two `int`s? Also, if the stopwatch was working, you're including the time `array.Clone()` and the cast of the result to `int[]` to both sorts. Sure, those could be the same for both sorts, but they could differ. I suggest moving it out and calling `GetArray` twice instead. I would also just use a method from one of the crypto libraries to get an array of random numbers.

Comment: `stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds` returns an integer value, and it will return zero if the elapsed time is less than one millisecond. Try using `stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds` instead, which is a floating-point value and accounts for sub-millisecond precision.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: Even if they cost the same the % difference between both sort methods is falsified then, so i would never measure unrelated things, if possible.

Comment: @Austin Added main as well. Doesn't really have anything interesting in it.

Comment: @JosephDaSilva This was it. Thanks.

Comment: Don't put answers in the question.  Just post your own in the box provided.

Comment: Don't write your own code for measuring performance. You're likely going to get it wrong. [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) is specifically for performance testing, and helps you actually test it correctly so you can be confident in the result.

Comment: @mason This was mainly supposed to be just a simple way to get an idea for the differences but when I saw it wasn't working I wanted to understand why.

Comment: @LarsTech shuold I still keep the implementation of my methods in the answer even thoght they are unrelated to the problem? Seems like it wouldn't be useful for someone with the same problem in the future...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a problem with the Stopwatch.

The very first time your sort code runs, it's taking much longer than subsequent times. This can happen due to JIT compilation, caching, and similar things that are completely outside of your control. It's taking long enough that the ElapsedMilliseconds value has a meaningful integer value (e.g. `3`), and so when you divide it by `1000` you end up with a number in the thousands place (e.g. `.003`).

Every other time the sort code runs, it's taking less than a millisecond. So all the `+=` operations are adding zero to the total. The sum of all those zeroes is zero.

Changing the `+= stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds` to `+= stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;` will fix that particular problem, and give you results more like this:

> Quicksort took an average of 0.003297300000000042 milliseconds to sort arrays with a length of 3.
> Mergesort took an average of 0.0019986999999999453 milliseconds to sort arrays with a length of 3.
> Quicksort took an average of 0.0013175999999999856 milliseconds to sort arrays with a length of 4.
> Mergesort took an average of 0.001030500000000005 milliseconds to sort arrays with a length of 4.
> Quicksort took an average of 0.001468300000000015 milliseconds to sort arrays with a length of 5.
> Mergesort took an average of 0.0011402999999999956 milliseconds to sort arrays with a length of 5.

However, there are other issues to fix.

- You're including the time spent cloning the array in your results.
- `Start()` should be switched to `Restart()`: right now the nth run of QuickSort is including the `n-1`th run of Mergesort in its time.
- The whole strategy of adding thousands of individual run times together still exposes you to rounding errors: they're just smaller with `double` than they are with `int`. You see all those `0000000`s and `999999`s in the results? A better strategy is typically to run the same sort a whole bunch of times and then see how much total time has passed.

In general, you're better off relying on a benchmarking framework rather than writing your own code. There are a lot of issues like these that you are unlikely to consider when writing your own.

Comment: Thank you! @JosephDaSilva already explained to me that I need to use stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds but I didn't realise I was including the time from the mergsort.

Comment: @YuvalAmir: no problem. Also note that your MergeSort implementation is suffering from the `Take`, `Skip` and `ToArray`. Try using a `Span<int>` and `Slice` it instead. You'll find that goes a lot faster, especially with compiler optimizations enabled. And your QuickSort algorithm can get caught in an infinite loop when there are two instances of the same value in the array.

Answer (score 0):

As @JosephDaSilva pointed out, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds returns an integer value which means it's going to round down to 0 if it was less then a milisecond. stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds should be used as it returns a floating-point value, which won't get rounded down.